# conda info showing the same old version after conda update in Linux

Tags: linux, conda

I followed the conda doc to update the conda on a google could server with this:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

after this, it shows:

```
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.11
  latest version: 4.12.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

then i try this:

```
conda update --all
```

the same output plus some packages and progress:

```
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.11
  latest version: 4.12.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda


## Package Plan ##

  environment location: <path>


The following packages will be downloaded:
<packages and progress>
```

then i run `conda info`

```
active environment : None
        shell level : 0
   user config file : <path>/.condarc


populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : 2.0.2
         python version : 3.5.6.final.0
       base environment : <path>/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : <path>/anaconda3/pkgs
                          <path>/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : <path>//anaconda3/envs
                          <path>//.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.5.6 Linux/5.13.0-1019-gcp ubuntu/20.04 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : <the ID>
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

There was no error during the last installation. but it seems it is still not updated, i did it not in any environment, i downloaded and installed the conda version 4.2.0 on this google cloud server, I want to know is my conda updated to 4.12 or not, if not how could i update it properly?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

While normally not recommend to update Python in-place, that is quite outdated and is likely what is preventing the `conda` package from being updated.

Try:

```bash
conda install -n base --dry-run python=3.9 conda=4.12
```

to see if updating is possible. If so, try again without the --dry-run flag.

⚠️ Note this is a risky update - if the `conda` package does not upgrade correctly with `python`, the installation could fail. I'd recommend a backup first.

Comment: thanks, the version did cross my mind when i install it, but i thought i could update along the way i was wrong. due to timing i have to make a new instance and install newer conda there luckily this time not a lot of files to move. i will try your suggestion when i run into this problem again and avoid installing old version in future